# Check if string matches String number pattern

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have strings that are a series of letters followed by numbers.

Example:

```
Avhfd0165
rhji9898
fbg5
b8
```

Given any string, I need to know if that string matches this string number pattern.

Therefore:

```
aghg7h
Hello
Moo 17
A81 B4
```

Would all be fail cases.

Is there a function in .Net that can allow me to spot this kind of expression pattern without having to parse it manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex for this: the expression `[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+` matches a non-empty sequence of letters followed by a non-empty sequence of digits:

```
string[] data = new[] {
    "aaa123", "123aaa", "123", "aaa", "a 1"
};
Regex r = new Regex("[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+");
foreach (string s in data) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", s, r.IsMatch(s));
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ykGB0k)